# Azure Data Factory Flow : Data Flow Sink Mapping

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

In : Azure Data Factory Flow : Data Flow Sink Mapping
on the mapping tab of the Sink:

"*At least one incoming column is mapped to a column in the sink dataset schema with a conflicting type, which can cause NULL values or runtime errors.*"

Is there some way of actually finding out what the offending column is?

Visual inspection confirms both outgoing transformation and snowflake table types are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading from ADF into Snowflake, I would recommend you load all columns of data into a single "variant" column in Snowflake. Then, once the data is safe and sound, you parse your variant column into multiple columns (complete with Data Quality checks and transformations)

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion. Now to sell my team mates on that idea!